# How do I DRY out these repeating jQuery selectors and functions?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I created this script and it works, but I know it repeats itself badly and needs to be DRY'ed out. I understand how to use variables for selectors but not sure how to not repeat the functions. Can anyone help?

```
// JS to add a "More" link to priority announcements when the height is too tall. 
$(document).ready(function(){
  // If JS is turned on add a height restriction to the announcement
  $(".importantNotice .content").addClass("maxHeight"); 
  // If the height is over 245 a "More" link apears
  if ($('.importantNotice .content').height() >= 245 || $('.importantNotice .content .landing-no-display').length) {
      $('.importantNotice .more').addClass("show");
    }
    // If the window gets resized it rechecks height
  $(window).resize(function(){ 
    if ($('.importantNotice .content').height() >= 245 || $('.importantNotice .content .landing-no-display').length) {
        $('.importantNotice .more').addClass("show");
        }
        if ($('.importantNotice .content').height() < 245 ($.contains('.importantNotice .content').not(':has(.landing-no-display)')) {
        $('.importantNotice .more').removeClass("show");
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Have you looked into `.toggleClass()`? http://api.jquery.com/toggleclass/

Comment: how would toggleClass help here? @JoeB.

Comment: Well for the resize couldn't you do. `if(//statement){ $('.importantNotice .more).toggleClass('show')  }` That way you wouldn't have to do `.addClass()`  and `removeClass()`?

Comment: No, because then it'd show and hide it repeatedly as the page is resized. You could do `.toggleClass('show', $('.importantNotice .content').height() >= 245 || $('.importantNotice .content .landing-no-display').length)` but that's certainly less readable than an if statement.

Comment: Seems like both your conditions are going to be true, or both false, every time:  `$('.importantNotice .content .landing-no-display').length` and `$('.importantNotice .content').find('landing-no-display').length` are equivalent, aren't they?  So you'll always add and then immediately remove the class, or you'll do nothing.  Therefore the DRY version of this is no code at all

Comment: @DanielBeck You are right. I had a mistake when I was trying to not remove the .show class when the .landing-no-display class is present. I fixed/updated it.

Comment: Good good -- that makes this easier (you can just if / else, as in Yury's answer below instead of having to spell out the full condition in both clauses.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would do this way to improve performance specially when using `resize` event

```
// JS to add a "More" link to priority announcements when the height is too tall. 
$(document).ready(function(){
  var importantElem = $(".importantNotice");
  var contentElem = importantElem.find('.content');
  var moreElem = importantElem.find('.more');
  var landingElem = contentElem.find('.landing-no-display');

  // If JS is turned on add a height restriction to the announcement
  contentElem.addClass("maxHeight"); 

  // If the window gets resized it rechecks height
  $(window).resize(function(){ 
    // If the height is over 245 a "More" link apears
    if (contentElem.height() >= 245 || landingElem.length) {
        moreElem.addClass("show");
    }else if (contentElem.height() < 245 || landingElem.length == 1) { //using else-if here to minimize the conditional checking 
        moreElem.removeClass("show");
    }
  }).trigger('resize');  //triggering `resize` for first time to aviod duplicate code
});
```

Comment: I ended up DRYing out my code by adding variables like this. I think it could be further optimized in the resize function, but I was running into problems trying to use Yury's solution above.

Comment: Maybe you can try reducing the variables but using `selectors` inside `resize` event will slow down the performance. Every time when you scroll, jQuery needs to find the same selector's element again and again. My solution is optimized and faster.

Answer (score 1):

As usually - define a function

```
function toggleMore() {
   var shouldShow = $('.importantNotice .content').height() >= 245
     || $('.importantNotice .content .landing-no-display').length

   $('.importantNotice .more').toggleClas("show", shouldShow)
}

$(function() {
  $(".importantNotice .content").addClass("maxHeight");

  toggleMore()
  $(window).resize(toggleMore)
})
```